# How do you run one daemon for multiple users?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, daemon

I have installed Bitcoin v0.18.1 as `user1`.
Everything is fine, but now I need to let `user2` access the same run so he can use `bitcoin-cli` as well.

However, once I log into the VM instance as `user2` I get this error:

`error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set.  See -rpcpassword and -stdinrpcpass.  Configuration file: (/home/user2/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

It does not matter if the users use the same wallet, I just need `bitcoin-cli` to work for both users and use data from `user1` (full sync)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bitcoin-cli` attempts to read the credentials from `$HOME/.bitcoin`. Since user2 will have a different home directory, bitcoin-cli will not able to find the credentials.

You can either symlink `.bitcoin` from user1's home directory to user2's, or alias `bitcoin-cli` for user2 to use `-datadir=user1home/.bitcoin`.

You may need to play around with the read permissions in either case.